# CodeIgniter : Show methods name as per model name selected

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, model, filesystems

I have 2 dropdown in one of my web page build with CodeIgniter. First dropdown is `Model Name` and second one is `Method Name`. I am able to pull all models from `model` directory by using `get_filenames()` and showing their names in the dropdown option. Now when user choose a model name from first dropdown I want to show all methods name declared on that model file in the second dropdown.

I'll do an ajax call and populate the second dropdown as per first dropdown selection. My question is how can I get methods name as per model selected.

Any idea how to do that!

Comment: Not good at all. My be your site cause to SQL Injection.

Comment: This is some requirements from my client for email trigger functionality. I have to choose a model and a method and when that's executed an email got fired.

Comment: Do you mean the methods from the class the model belongs to? May be you can use `get_class_methods()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php

Comment: hard code it. don't show all function to view.

Comment: Hard code is not a good idea at all. I can still filters on the list which needed to show!

Comment: Thanks @Tom, that's working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$methods = get_class_methods('classname');
print_r($methods);
```

But not a good idea to show method and file names. To avoid this we use `MVC`

See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d6d8cf35b1dad54ca161f1c93123ec680a8a395)

Comment: Glad it helped you. Consider accepting the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: BTW the method support class instance as a param as well and that's work for me.